# Integer Array or Individual Integers?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, memory-management, int

Say if i want a array of 4 int's

ex.

```
int[] iA = {32,33,34,35};
```

would this array take up more memory than declaring them as individual Int's?

ex.

```
int i0 = 32;
int i1 = 33;
int i2 = 34;
int i3 = 35;
```

Comment: Where are those variable declarations? Local or instance/class?

Comment: it's a kind of pointless question. If you need an array, you need an array...

Comment: Do you care about heap memory versus stack?

Comment: @user3180189, please update your code with a dummy class so that this aspect of the question become clear

Answer (score 2):

Each int is a primitive data type, whose sizes are defined in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html.

The array is an object, which carries some overhead. There is a good discussion on how to find the size of Java objects in [how calculate java array memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972578/how-calculate-java-array-memory-usage).

Comment: Java does to my knowledge not specify how much memory a primitive use. And they might all be stored in at least 4bytes even when they would need only 2 or less.

Comment: Did you click on the link above, the one pointing to the Oracle site?

Comment: That are the sizes that you see in your program. That are not necessarily the sizes the JVM allocates to store them. 32bit / 64bit aligned memory is faster to access than using odd byte numbers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229886/size-of-a-byte-in-memory-java / similar thing: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops

Answer (score 2):

Space saving should not be the first concern influencing your decision here. You should think of answers to these questions:

- **Could the number of `int`s change in the future** - if the answer is "yes", then you need an array.
- **Do you need "addressability" over your integers?** - in other words, if you are given an index of, say, `3`, do you need an ability to access `i3`? If the answer is "yes", you definitely need an array.

To answer your question, an array would take a few additional bytes of memory, because Java needs to allocate space to the array object itself. This overhead is noticeable when the number of `int`s is small, but it quickly goes down as your array grows.

Answer (score 1):

Individual int will take less memory as there is

1. Less array reference involved.
2. No object padding involved

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/

Comment: You are making unwarranted assumptions.  From the link that you posted: *"Moreover, the memory usage is typically padded to be a multiple of 8 bytes (on a 64-bit machine)."*