# Java memory usage by array objects

Tags: java, heap-memory, stack-memory

How many heap space takes array object? I mean not a array reference.
For example how many heap space will take this array

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[5];
```

Or perhaps you know some ways how I can to test memory usage of my application? Any suggestions and advices will be appreciated)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to google it?

Comment: Have you ever seen [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you want to read the layout of a given object and its size you could use [JOL](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/).

Comment: @eckes thanks for your comment, as far as I see this thing is suitable for my purpose (wow it show how many space each Object use and many other interesting information)

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the array is of primitive type of object types. If it is 
int[] = new int[5] it will be 5 times int memory size - 5x4=20 bytes.

If it is Object and not primitive like in your case (Integer) then the memory used is the number of the object multiplied by reference memory size ( the pointer size ) - 32 bits or 64 bits depending on the JVM.

Comment: An array has a type pointer and size field in addition to the actual elements, so it is typically (count+1)*oopsize + intsize.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you mean:

`Integer[] array = new Integer[5];`

And integers are 4 bytes when being used... so 4*5= 20 bytes. But there is more to it than just this.. Certain overhead on the array's in such and the fact you are using the Integer class rather than just doing:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
```

I would suggest trying to google for a more explained answer or go here:
[Calculating Java Array Memory Usuage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972578/how-calculate-java-array-memory-usage)

Comment: @eckes Yes... I shortly explained that in my answer...