# Trying to understand the footprint of ArrayList in JOLSample_16_AL_LL

Tags: java, arraylist, jvm, jol

Here is a link to the code in question - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jol/file/07087260ce41/jol-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jol/samples/JOLSample_16_AL_LL.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    out.println(VM.current().details());

    List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Integer io = i; // box once
        al.add(io);
        ll.add(io);
    }

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
    pw.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(al).toFootprint());
    pw.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(ll).toFootprint());
    pw.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(al, ll).toFootprint());
    pw.close();
}
```

When I run the code as is I see the following:

```
java.util.ArrayList@5f205aad footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
         1      4952      4952   [Ljava.lang.Object;
      1000        16     16000   java.lang.Integer
         1        24        24   java.util.ArrayList
      1002               20976   (total)
```

I am unsure where the 4952 bytes for [Ljava.lang.Object; is coming from. If I update the ArrayList creation and set a initial size to 1000 so that there is no growing I get the following:

```
java.util.ArrayList@5f205aad footprint:
 COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
     1      4016      4016   [Ljava.lang.Object;
  1000        16     16000   java.lang.Integer
     1        24        24   java.util.ArrayList
  1002               20040   (total)
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I turned off CompressedOops (-XX:-UseCompressedOops). Here is the new result:

```
java.util.ArrayList@1996cd68d footprint:
 COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
     1      8024      8024   [Ljava.lang.Object;
  1000        24     24000   java.lang.Integer
     1        40        40   java.util.ArrayList
  1002               32064   (total)
```

So when disabling CompressedOops the reference sizes increase to 8 bytes. To me that makes even more sense that the Object array holds the references to the 1000 Integer Objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList` internally is backed by an `Object[]` as a buffer, which [grows as needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4450689/5743988).

An array of objects is actually an array of object references. In your case, it looks like each object reference is [4 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/981073/5743988), so an array of them would use `4 * length` bytes, plus some overhead such as the length of the array [and other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2972578/5743988).

When you allow the `ArrayList` to grow naturally, any unused indexes in the buffer array default to `null`, which still uses 4 bytes of memory per index.

The `ArrayList` that *allows* growth has probably expanded to (4952 - 16) / 4 = **~1234 capacity**.

While the `ArrayList` that doesn't require growth only has **1000 capacity**.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: On a 32-bit architecture an object reference is 4 bytes (32-bits), and on a 64-bit architecture an object reference is 8 bytes, but some JVMs can compress to 4 bytes.

Comment: My machine was running a 64-bit JVM, but showing object references as 32-bits. That is part of the reason why I was confused. When I turn off CompressedOops (-XX:-UseCompressedOops) the references went to 64-bits. I added an update to my original question to show this.

Comment: @Jon Right, my comment was in response to your update, just for completeness. The link on "4 bytes" in my answer talks about it also.