# Question about sizeof. I want to reverse bits in number

Tags: java, loops, integer, bit-manipulation, sizeof

What will be equivalent of this in Java?

```
for (i = (sizeof(num)*8-1); i; i--)
```

`num` is given number, not array. I want to reverse bits in integer.

Comment: `i–`? with the en dash? I guess you meant `i--` and edited your question accordingly, feel free to revert if I was wrong!

Comment: BTW, int values are always 32 bit in java.  They don't vary like they can in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java does not have `sizeof`. Arrays have the `length` property, and many collections have `size()` and similar things like that, but a linguistic `sizeof` for any arbitrary object is both not supported and not needed.

#### Related questions

- [Is there any sizeof-like method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370288/is-there-any-sizeof-like-method-in-java)
- [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

---

#### Getting bits of an integer in LSB-MSB order

To get the bits of an integer from its [least significant bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit) to its [most significant bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit), you can do something like this:

```
    int num = 0xABCD1234;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(num));
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.SIZE; i++) {
        System.out.print((num >> i) & 1);
    }
```

This prints:

```
10101011110011010001001000110100    // MSB-LSB order from toBinaryString
00101100010010001011001111010101    // LSB-MSB order from the loop
```

So in this specific case, the `sizeof * 8` translates to [`Integer.SIZE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#SIZE), "the number of bits used to represent an int value in two's complement binary form". In Java, this is fixed at 32.

> #### [JLS 4.2.1 Integral types and values](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1)
>
> For `int`, from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`, inclusive

Answer (score 1):

This loop is likely iterating over an array in reverse order. In this case, it is an array of 'num' objects, and there are 8 elements in the array (the '-1' is necessary because an array of 8 elements has valid indices 0...7).

To do that in Java, the equivalent would be:

```
for(int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; --i)
```

Answer (score 0):

in C/C++, the sizeof operator tells you how many bytes a variable or type takes on the current target platform.  That is to say, it depends on the target platform, and therefore there is a keyword for discovering it.

Java targets a virtual machine, and the size of types is constant.

If num is an int, it is 4 bytes (32-bits).  If it is long, it is 8 bytes (64 bits).

Furthermore, you cannot treat a variable as an array of bytes.  You have to use bitwise operators (shifts, and, or etc) to manipulate the bits in a primitive like an int or long.

Comment: Strictly speaking an `int` is never defined to by 4 bytes at runtime in Java. The only thing that is defined is the possible value range of an `int` (which strongly hints at a 4-byte `int`) and how `int` constants are stored in class files. Those do **not** mean that an `int` must be exactly 4 bytes, however.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct equivalent. The sizeof returns the size of a type or the type of the expression in bytes, and this information is not available in Java.

It's not required as the sizes in bytes of the built-in types are fixed, lengths of arrays are obtained using the `.length` psuedo-field, and memory for objects is allocated using `new`, so the object size is not required.

If you tell use what the type of num is, then it can be translated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to polygenelubricants' answer, there's another way to reverse the bits of an integer in Java:

```
int reversed = Integer.reverse(input);
```

Easy!

It's worth checkout the source code for Integer.reverse, it's rather nifty (and extremely scary).