# How to calculate the size of class in java ..?is any method like sizeof() in c..?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any sizeof-like method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370288/is-there-any-sizeof-like-method-in-java)

I want to determine the size of my class at runtime. In C i do this:

```
struct
{
int id;
char name[30];
} registry


void main()
{
int size = sizeof(registry);
}
```

How i can do this in Java ?

Comment: that is the size of the object, right? not the size of the class (with the byte code for method definitions and such)

Comment: What do you want to do with the numbers? There may be a way to do what you want without having to know the explicit size...

Comment: Possible since Java 5 using java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The Java virtual machine doesn't want you to know it.

There are probably other ways to do what you really wanted to do with this information.

Comment: ya i want to know how to calculate

Comment: That way of phrasing it sounds odd to me.  It makes it sound like they're just being mean!  :-)  I'd say: the JVM design says JVM implementers are allowed to perform optimizations which are enabled by not needing to expose the 'size' of objects (or even have it constant per-object, or over time).

Answer (score 1):

VMs differ in how they store variables, etc internally.  Most modern 32-bit VMs are similar though.  You can probably estimate the shallow size of a class instance like this:

```
sizeInBytes = C + 4 * (fieldCount)
```

Where C is some constant.

This is because typically all fields are given a word width, which is often still 4 bytes internally to the JVM.  The deep size of the class is more difficult to compute, but basically you recursively add the size of each referent object.  Arrays are typically `1*arr.length` bytes in size for booleans and bytes, `2*arr.length` for chars and shorts, `4*arr.length` for ints and floats, and `8*arr.length` for doubles and longs.

Probably the easiest way to get an estimate at runtime is to measure how `Runtime.freeMemory()` changes as you instantiate objects of your class.  None of this should be used for program logic of course; just for JVM tweaking or curiousity.

Comment: `boolean` in HotSpot VM is actually 8 bytes but otherwise this is all good :)

Comment: @Esko `boolean` is eight __bytes__?

Comment: ...bits! Damn you, edit time expiration and morning slowness.

Comment: @Esko: Yes, it looks like you're right that booleans can now be packed into a byte.  But after some testing it looks like it's more complicated than that due to word-alignment, etc.  Bytes, shorts and chars are similar, they can be packed into sub-word locations.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ClassMexer](http://www.javamex.com/classmexer/) which is just a simple implementation of the new java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation interface. Just follow the instructions, which are pretty simple.

It may be too intrusive for your use as it runs as javaagent but from your example it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an estimate, getting the exact number if difficult. Why is it necessary?