# Best practice for getting datatype size(sizeof) in Java

Tags: java, sizeof

I want store a list of doubles and ints to a ByteBuffer, which asks for a size to allocate. I'd like to write something like C's syntax

```
int size=numDouble*sizeof(double)+numInt*sizeof(int);
```

But there is no `sizeof` in Java. What is the best practice to calculate the size in byte? Should I hardcode it?

Comment: The [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2) specifies the size of primitive types exactly. (but I'm not seeing the size of a boolean in there)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

See [@Frank Kusters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766343/best-practice-for-getting-datatype-sizesizeof-in-java/24824883#24824883), below!

(My original answer here was for Java versions < 8.)

Comment: I put in an [enhancement suggestion](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=668&can=6&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary) for Guava to make this a little less verbose.

Comment: So there is no way to find the size of primitive data types, but we can find the size of the wrapper classes, Is it correct? @Ed Staub

Comment: @Pie No.  The constant is provided by the wrapper class, but it is the size of the primitive.

Answer (score 39):

Since Java 8, all wrapper classes of primitive types (except `Boolean`) have a `BYTES` field. So in your case:

```
int size = numDouble * Double.BYTES + numInt * Integer.BYTES;
```

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: This is simpler than the accepted answer and should be the new accepted answer IMO

Answer (score 9):

Write your own method. In Java the datatypes are platform independent always the same size:

```
public static int sizeof(Class dataType)
{
    if (dataType == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    if (dataType == int.class    || dataType == Integer.class)   return 4;
    if (dataType == short.class  || dataType == Short.class)     return 2;
    if (dataType == byte.class   || dataType == Byte.class)      return 1;
    if (dataType == char.class   || dataType == Character.class) return 2;
    if (dataType == long.class   || dataType == Long.class)      return 8;
    if (dataType == float.class  || dataType == Float.class)     return 4;
    if (dataType == double.class || dataType == Double.class)    return 8;

    return 4; // 32-bit memory pointer... 
              // (I'm not sure how this works on a 64-bit OS)
}
```

Usage:

```
int size = numDouble * sizeof(double.class) + numInt * sizeof(int.class);
```

Comment: suggestion: use `switch case` for better readability, java 7 supports strings in switch statements.

Comment: I think the readability is great. Using Strings would ruin performance.

Comment: this is not correct: the classes have overhead compared to the primitive types. 
An Integer will required more memory than the equivalent int.

Answer (score 5):

A better solution might be to not emulate C syntax and use an ObjectOutputStream with a nested ByteArrayOutputStream to generate a byte array which can then be written to your ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 3):

The size in Java is always the same. You can hardcode it but you only need to do this because you are working with bytes in a ByteBuffer. If you use `double[]` or `DoubleBuffer` you don't need these.

Comment: With the focus on NIO.2 in JDK 7. This answer is the best practice.

Comment: Not if you are using NIO to interface with other APIs such as OpenGL which still require number of bytes (not numbers).

Comment: What is the size in java?

Comment: @Joehot200 when you create a ByteBuffer you have to give it a size in byte.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [sizeof4j](https://github.com/arturmkrtchyan/sizeof4j) library to get the sizeof the double you just need `SizeOf.doubleSize()`

Answer (score 0):

Automated and abstract solution is to write the sample to DataOutput and see the resulted size.