# Does Java have an operator like sizeof() in C?

Tags: java, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any sizeof-like method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370288/is-there-any-sizeof-like-method-in-java)

Does Java have operator something like sizeof() in C?

Comment: no.............

Comment: What are you trying to do which would need it?  Most memory profilers will tell you how much memory is being used by what.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-12/02-qa-1226-sizeof.html?page=2

Comment: If you want to find out if something exists in Java, try searching for `java xxxx`. `java sizeof` gets many hits, including Stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **no**.

However there are some simple approaches to achieve that. Write your own sizeof method.

```
public static int sizeof(Class cl)
{
    if (cl == Integer.class || cl == int.class) return 4;
    if (cl == Character.class || cl == char.class) return 2;
    //...
}
```

The size of the object will depend on the JVM implementation. There is the Java [SizeOf](http://sizeof.sourceforge.net) project which handles all cases correctly.

Comment: There are _many_ classes, not just those encapsulating primitive data types.

Comment: Actually, you can get the size fairly accurately, see https://github.com/jbellis/jamm, "MemoryMeter is as accurate as
java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.getObjectSize"