# How to measure HTTP-Session Size?

Tags: session, tomcat

Is there some effective and accurate way to track the size of a particular session in a servlet based application?

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have a `sizeof()` method like C (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370288/is-there-any-sizeof-like-method-in-java) for more information) so you generally can't get the size of *anything* in Java.  However, you can track what goes into and is removed from the session with a [HttpSessionAttributeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html) (link is JavaEE 8 and below).  This will give you some visibility into the number of attributes and, to an extent, the amount of memory being used.  Something like:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionAttributeListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent;

@WebListener
public class MySessionAttributeListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {
    
    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        System.out.println( "the attribute \"" + event.getName() + "\" with the value \"" + event.getValue() + "\" has been added" );
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        System.our.println( "the attribute \"" + event.getName() + "\" with the value \"" + event.getValue() + "\" has been removed" );     
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        System.out.println( "the attribute \"" + event.getName() + "\" with the value \"" + event.getValue() + "\" has been replaced" );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also serialize a session to bytes (or onto the disk) and look at how big the output is. This doesn't map directly to object-size-in-memory but it will be in the same ballpark.